# Build library using JitPack

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I have a problem. I created test library and push it to Github. But when I try to include this library into (using Gradle) project show error [showing error](http://prntscr.com/fvpifv)

But log into jitpack.io show that build was sucsessful. Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your github repository contains an app and a library.

At tag `1.0.0` your repository publishes the app. At tag `1.0.1` it publishes the library.

According to your screenshot you try to include version `1.0.0` into your build, which resolves to the app.